# how to add percentage sign along with int value in graph in java script

Tags: javascript, web, highcharts

I am creating High Charts using java script they are working fine but i want that along with answers variable they should also show percentage % sign i have three variable ans66 ans67 and ans68 i want along with their values it should also show %

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       ans66=0;
       ans67=0;
       ans68=0;
       ans69=0;
       var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
         chart: {
           renderTo: 'container_1',
           defaultSeriesType: 'column'
         },
         xAxis: {
           categories: [''],
              title: {
                 text: 'Revenue base on one trip/one 4-pack per year',
                 style: {
                     color: '#767575'
                 }},
                 labels: {
                     align: 'right',
                     style: {
                         font: 'normal 11px Verdana'
                     },
                     x: 24,
                 }
              },
              yAxis: {
                 min: 0,
                 startOnTick: false,
                 labels: {
                 formatter: function() {
                     return this.value;
                 },
                style: {
                     color: '#767575'
                }
              },
              title: {
                text: '$',
                style: {
                   color: '#767575'
                }
              }
          },
          series: [{
               name: 'Revenue $',
               data: [ans66]
            }, {
               name: 'Revenue $',
               data: [ans67]
            }, {
               name: 'Revenue $',
               data: [ans68]
            }, {
               name: 'Revenue $',
               data: [ans69]
            }] 
         });
     });
```

Comment: Where do you want to show % sign ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're comparing series you just have to add the following code.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        compare: 'percent'
    }
}
```

Or you can add [`valuePrefix`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.valuePrefix), in my opinion it's the best way. You don't have to format each serie point:

```
tooltip: {
    valuePrefix: '%'
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Nt2z/)

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation is do in javascript with `+` char, example

```
var ans89pct = ans89 + '%';
```

You probably need to replace in your code :

```
   ...
        series: [{
           name: 'Revenue $',
           data: [ans66 + '%']
        }, {
           name: 'Revenue $',
           data: [ans67 + '%']
        }, {
           name: 'Revenue $',
           data: [ans68 + '%']
        }, {
           name: 'Revenue $',
           data: [ans69 + '%']
        }] 
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't clearly mentioned where exactly, you want to append Percentage sign.

So, I took your code and created a sample fiddle.

Change 1:

```
yAxis: {
                 min: 0,
                 startOnTick: false,
                 labels: {
                 formatter: function() {
                     return this.value + ' %';
                 },
                style: {
                     color: '#767575'
                }
              },
```

On a side note, You should create an Array by adding all JS variable in it. This will give you better readability and will reduce code redundancy.

Example:

```
var myArray = [11,12,9,13];

series: [{
               name: 'Revenue $',
               data: myArray
            }] 
         });
```